# No show string between round brackets SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with these rows as example:

*City:*

```
San Francisco (CA)
Miami (FL)
```

As a result I want this:

*City:*

```
San Francisco
Miami
```

Any help?

Regards.

Comment: `SUBSTR()` and  `INSTR()`

Comment: Can you possibly have more than one bracketed expression in the same field?  What version of Oracle?

Comment: Do you have to worry about meaningful data AFTER the brackets? Or does the first open bracket always signify the end of what you want? If so,  as HART CO said, INSTR() will find that first bracket for you. SUBSTR can extract the string up to the value you got from INSTR()

Comment: All cities have the state between round brackets, but just one time,  Los Angeles (CA), New York (NY), Charlotte (NC), Washington (DC) ...

I need to remove the state and get this:
Los Angeles, New York, Charlotte, Washington ...

The Database Version is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64 Bits.

The round bracket is always the end, I tried with INSTR and SUBSTR but I didn't get the output as I need it.

Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEX_REPLACE`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(City VARCHAR(120));

INSERT INTO tab
VALUES ('San Francisco (CA)');

INSERT INTO tab
VALUES ('Miami (FL)');

SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(city, '\((.+?)\)', '')) AS City
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12cda/4/0)**</kbd>

If you want to `UPDATE` you can use:

```
UPDATE tab
SET City = TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(city, '\((.+?)\)', ''))
WHERE INSTR(City, '(') > 0;

SELECT City
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12cda/5/1)**</kbd>

Comment: @Brino This site is very useful for fast prototyping/sharing concepts and allow others to play with demos. For SQL Server you can also use https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: **For funny downvoter you can leave a comment so I could reply and/or improve my answer**

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of argument, here's a REGEXP_SUBSTR( ) example.  It assumes you want to keep everything from the start of the strin up to but not including the space before the first open paren.

```
SQL> with tbl(city) as (
     select 'San Francisco (CA)' from dual
     union
     select 'Miami (FL)' from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(city, '^(.*) \(.*$', 1, 1, null, 1) new_city
   from tbl;

NEW_CITY
------------------
Miami
San Francisco

SQL>
```

EDIT:  Added a REGEXP_REPLACE solution that does not require a TRIM():

```
with tbl(city) as (
  select 'San Francisco (CA)' from dual
  union
  select 'Miami (FL)' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(city, '^(.*) \(.*$', '\1') new_city
from tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do something like

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN INSTR(CITY, '(') > 2 THEN
           SUBSTR(CITY, 1, INSTR(CITY, '(')-2)
         ELSE CITY
       END AS CITY
  FROM CITIES;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99220/7)

Best of luck.